# Relation between $a$ & $d$ in the ratio of arithmetic progressions $ (S_n/S_{k.n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Q:If $S_n$ denotes the sum of $n$ terms of an A.P. and $ (S_n/S_{k.n})$
> is independent of $n$, then what is the relation between $a$(first term) and $d$(common difference)?

Note:Here $S_{kn} \text{ denotes sum of first } (k*n) \text{ terms. } $

---

I did the following:
$\frac{S_n}{S{kn}} = ({(\frac n2)(2a + (n-1)d)})/({(\frac{k.n}{2})(2a+(kn - 1)d}) \\ = ({(2a + (n-1)d)})/({(k)(2a+(kn - 1)d})$
In order to remove n from the equation, $2a \text{ must be equal to  }d \text{ which gives } \frac{S_n}{S_{}kn} = \frac1{k^2} $.

---

So how do I prove $2a = d$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours will be
$$\frac{dn+2a-d}{dk^2n+2ak-dk}=\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{(2a-d)\left(1-\frac 1k\right)}{dk^2n+2ak-dk}.$$

Hence, since this value is independent of $n$, the numerator has to be zero. Hence, we have
$$2a-d=0\ \text{or}\ 1-\frac 1k=0\iff\ 2a=d\ \text{or}\ k=1.$$
Now $k=1$ means $\frac{S_n}{S_n}=1$ is independent of $n$. This is obvious. Hence, we have $2a=d$ as the relation between $a$ and $d$. This is what you want.

Comment: If $2a = d$, then we get $S_n/S_{kn} = \frac{d*n}{k*d*n} = 1/k^2$

Comment: Yes, but remember that this value is independent of $n$.

Comment: So, the numerator has to be zero. then, $2a=d$ or $k=1$.

Comment: where did you bring the $1/k^2 $ from?

Comment: I just divided it by treating them as polynomials of $n$.

Comment: divided what by what?

Comment: I divided $dn+2a-d$ by $dk^2n+2ak-dk$ by treating these two as polynomials of $n$.

Comment: that was easy. Thanks!

Comment: OK, my pleasure!